# Samba Tuning (Very low data transfer rates)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, samba

I have been trying to tune my Samba server for a while now and have had very little luck. At first I thought it could have had something to do with my router but recently purchased a new one with 10/100/1000 connections. The Samba server and Windows PC that access it are both wired directly to the router.

The maximum speed I am able to obtain is 11 Mbps which seems odd to me because I have (now) a very fast LAN and also the Samba Server has a very good 1TB 7200 RPM HDD.

My conf file is as follows

```
socket options = TCP_NODELAY

[BackupHDD]
path = /media/BackupHDD
available = yes
valid users = user
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Very simple yet I still cannot manage over 11 Mbps. Putting in the socket option is what allowed me to go from 3 Mbps to 11. Is there anything else you guys could suggest? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that helps.

Any information would be great. Theortically I should be able to obtain much higher speeds right? I know the HDD specs posted much much higher read write speeds.

Edit: I would just like to point out that the network drive I am using has about a speed transfer of 50 +/- Mbps according to the dd command.

```
dd if=/media/BackupHDD/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 1.9879 s, 52.7 MB/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to speed up Samba. Alone Samba is actually more tuned then I have realized. I stopped trying to tune the software itself and stepped backed and looked at my hardware. I noticed my Samba server was only running a 10/100 Ethernet port. I bought and installed a 10/100/1000 along with the 10/100/1000 router and all Cat 6 cables.

Now my speeds have increased up to 30-35 Mbps. While this is much better I know the HDD can preform about 50-55 Mbps. I am wondering if I can tweak it just a little more, but I assume a good amount of transfer speed is lost across the network and other hardware pieces.

Before anyone assumes Samba software being poor, I recommend you look at your hardware making sure that your LAN is truly a gigabit LAN.